# How to make a delimiter in c# and take the value

Tags: c#, arrays, string, delimiter

C# Visual Studio 17

Just assume I have a string which has the value [3-4+6*2] or even [3-4+20-0.5]
... and I want them to be stored in a string array... I've researched and found that using **split, trim start, trim end** We can separate them...

```
.TrimStart('[')
.TrimEnd(']')
.Split('-','*','+');
```

But I was unable to find whether we can do this I mean

 But I couldn't find anywhere how to store the delimiters too but have them do their work(i meant separating)!!

The value stored will be { 3, 4, 6, 2 } but I want this { 3, -, 4, +, 6, *, 2 } 
and what do I do with the extraordinary zeroes!!!?

Comment: Please update your question with the most worst scenario and the expected result. Maybe [-0.5*1,000.5+5,000-(7+5)] => ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *general* case, you have to use a *parser*; if want just to split and preserve the delimiter, please, have a look at `Regex.Split`:

```
  string source = "[-3*4+20-0.5/-4.1]";

  //TODO: specify the delimiters:
  // If you want more delimiters, e.g. (, ), [, ] etc. 
  // for, say, 9*[(456+789)/(95-2.96)-3]
  // just add them into the array
  char[] delimiters = new char[]  { '*', '+', '-', '/' };

  string pattern = "(" + string.Join("|", delimiters
    .Select(item => Regex.Escape(item.ToString()))) + ")";

  string[] result = Regex
    .Split(source.TrimStart('[').TrimEnd(']'), pattern) // (...) preserves delim
    .Select(item => item.Trim()) // <- if you want to trim each item 
    .Where(item => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item))
    .ToArray();

  // -, 3, *, 4, +, 20, -, 0.5, /, -, 4.1
  Console.Write(string.Join(", ", result));
```

**Edit**: For large texts you may want to implement the Split manually:

```
public static List<string> SplitPreserveSeparators(string source, char[] delimiters) {
  if (null == source)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("source") 
  else if (delimiters == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("delimiters") 

  int start = 0;
  int index = -1;

  List<string> items = new List<string>();

  while ((index = source.IndexOfAny(delimiters, start)) >= 0) {
    string value = source.Substring(start, index - start);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
      items.Add(value);

    items.Add(source.Substring(index, 1));
    start = index + 1;
  }

  if (start < source.Length)
    items.Add(source.Substring(start));

  return items;
}
```

And use it

```
string source = "[-3-4+20-0.5/-4.1]";
char[] delimiters = new char[]  { '*', '+', '-', '/' };

List<string> result =  SplitPreserveSeparators(
  source.TrimStart('[').TrimEnd(']'),
  delimiters);

Console.Write(string.Join(", ", result));
```

Comment: @Lanorkin: Nice catch! Thank you! Empty strings should have been removed (I've edited the asnwer). In general case there's no alternative to a parser

Comment: The example from the question is very bad describing only a very simple case. We need a very complex or even the most worst scenario to offer a working answer. The current question can be solved by taking the char array from the inner string.

Comment: @Sir Rufo: Quite right, I've edited the test input (aggravated one from the question - `/-4.1` term added); however, exponetial format is not supported - `"1e-2"` will be split into `1e, -, 2`

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a simple custom extension method for splitting with stored separators:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string[] SplitStoreSeparators(this string input, char[] separators) 
    {
        List<string> tokens = new List<string>();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
        foreach (var c in input)
        {
            if (separators.Contains(c)) {
                if (sb.Length > 0) {
                    tokens.Add(sb.ToString());
                    sb.Clear();
                }
                tokens.Add(c.ToString());
            } else {
                sb.Append(c);
            }
        }

        if (sb.Length > 0)
            tokens.Add(sb.ToString());

        return tokens.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine().TrimStart('[').TrimEnd(']');
string[] output = input.SplitStoreSeparators(new[] { '+', '-', '/', '*' });
```

Comment: @Lanorkin I was too short-sighted about this problem. I have updated my answer.

Comment: `string current = "";  ... current += c;` is not a good role for `string` (esp. if you have a large text to parse); `StringBuilder current = ... current.Append(c);`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko You are absolutely right. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, enumerating this string and store each element in a result array, skipping the first and the last element will give the result you want.

Answer (score -1):

A string is an array of characters. As such, you can use the `String.ToCharArray()` method to store it as an array.
To remove the first and last characters, we can pass in an `int` for the start index, and an `int` for the required length.

For example:

```
string myString = "[3-4+6*2]";

char[] myArray = myString.ToCharArray(1, myString.Length-2);
```

This will remove the first and last characters of the string and store each remaining character in an array.

Comment: The question is not about how to store the delimiters. The question was about how to store the delimiters AND the characters in an array. If you have removed your comment, please also consider removing your down vote.

Comment: But that does not split on the delimeters. What about "[10+12]"?